# ‘SSL_R_SHORT_READ’ was not declared in this scope error while installing rstudio-desktop-1.0.143

Tags: c++, cmake, archlinux

I have R-3.4.0 installed in a x86 system, and want to install the newest rstudio-desktop from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rstudio-desktop). I used MaoCPU's patch file at the comments and then run makepkg -sri after some time an error appeared saying :

```
 /home/orbitz/.bin/AUR/rstudio-desktop/src/rstudio-rstudio-adca7c8/src/cpp/core/http/SocketProxy.cpp:152:60: error: ‘SSL_R_SHORT_READ’ was not declared in this scope  error.code().value() == ERR_PACK(ERR_LIB_SSL, 0, SSL_R_SHORT_READ);
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/k0VU6JAS) is a complete output of the procedure. Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this ?

P.S I also tried to install the previous version (rstudio-desktop 1.0.136-2) but with the same result.

Comment: Do you figure out how to build? I faced the same problem? I've installed openssl both 1.0 & 1.1.0.

Comment: Actually I used the .patch file I posted in your above comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arch Linux recently migrated [openssl](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/openssl/) to 1.1.0.

If R hasn't been updated, you probably need to install [openssl-1.0](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/openssl-1.0/) for compatibility. See the [migration todo list](https://www.archlinux.org/todo/openssl-110-rebuild/) for details.

Comment: I've added these on CMAKE line of PKGBUILD, but can not work. Do you build successfully?  -DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/openssl-1.0 -DOPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0/libssl.so -DOPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0/libcrypto.so

Comment: @DanielYCLin Unfortunately, it looks like their cmake setup is a little different, so you need to change how to pass the overrides. `-DOPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS=/usr/include/openssl-1.0 -DOPENSSL_LIBRARIES='-L/usr/lib/openssl-1.0 -lssl -lcrypto'` might work? Also don't forget to change the dependency.

Comment: You can use [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/870e853c7045158bae2ab79bfd27179a) patch for PKGBUILD file if you are using arch linux.